# AWS X-RAY traces report for one month

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-xray

We are using AWS X-Ray traces in our EKS Fargate cluster to trace requests. The sampling rate is not configured and hence it is 100%.

Currently, AWS X-Ray UI provide us with a way to search traces for 6 hour range.

Is there any way we can find traces for a month? Basically, I wanted to check how many https://example.com/service1/api1 APIs were invoked last month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trace data are stored in X-Ray for 30 days, see https://aws.amazon.com/xray/faqs/

Seems like console options are limited, you might need to use API to achieve what you need, see query traces API https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-api-gettingdata.html#xray-api-traces